# Form from another module not rendering properly

Tags: forms, ubercart

I am attempting to call uc_shipping_new_shipment() (apart of Ubercart) in my custom function that handles its own shipping.  When I load my page dpm() prints out what looks like an appropriate form.  However, the form does not load on the page.  What am I doing wrong?

```
function my_module_ship($uid, $order_id) {
  $order = uc_order_load($order_id);
  module_load_include('inc', 'uc_shipping', 'uc_shipping.admin');
  $form = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('uc_shipping_new_shipment', $order));
  dpm($form);
  return $form;
}
```

I have tried it with and without drupal_render().

Comment: I usually use dsm()? what is the difference from dpm anyways?

Comment: @duckx `dsm()` is deprecated in favour of `dpm()`, it just calls the same function internally